# Upgrade from asp.net-core 2.0 preview1 to asp.net-core 2.0 preview2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I built an application in asp.net-core 2.0 preview1

Now I want to upgrade to asp.net-core 2.0 preview2

But I run into bunch of issues with namespaces:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Service
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Service.EntityFrameworkCore (deoesn't exist anymore)
```

etc...

I heard that they change the way of authorization, but is there any documentation how I can get code working.

For example: `IdentityServiceOptions.LoginPolicyName` doesn't exist anymore, `IdentityServiceApplication` as well etc..

I didn't post any code as now it's mess.

But the help I need is if anyone is familiar with this to refer to some documentation or anything that can help.

Thanks

I am using package: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`

Comment: you can look around in the source code for changes https://github.com/aspnet/Identity